# Graph Simulation in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, graph

Given `m` set of descriptions of **undirected** graph as a vertex pair, create a program that outputs the whole graph such that they are sorted as well as their vertices.

Example:

```
Vertices: [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
m = 8 (Descriptions)

Descriptions:
A B
C B
E C
D C
G D
F D
D E
E F

Output:
A: B
B: A C
C: B D E
D: C E F G
E: C D F
F: D E
G: D
```

I made a code that uses a Dictionary to append a vertex but I don't know how to deal with duplicates.

```
Ex. 
A B
A B
```

My code prints `A: B B` and `B: A A`, And since this runs at O(n), is my approach the *fastest*?

Code:

```
d = {}
string = input().split()
m = int(input())

for j in range(m):
    temp = input().split()
    if temp[0] in d: d[temp[0]].append(temp[1])
    else: d[temp[0]] = list(temp[1])
    
    if temp[1] in d: d[temp[1]].append(temp[0])
    else: d[temp[1]] = list(temp[0])


for j in sorted(d):
    d[j].sort()
    print(j + ": ", end='')
    print(*set(d[j]))
```

Sample Input:

```
A B C D E F G
8
A B
C B
E C
D C
G D
F D
D E
E F
```

Comment: You can avoid the duplicate issue by using a dictionary of `set` instead of a dictionary of `list`.

Comment: Seems to work, now my only inquiry is if this is the fastest approach.

Comment: I also suggest using `collections.defaultdict` instead of a standard dictionary to avoid the check `if temp[0] in d:`

Comment: May I know how that would improve runtime?

Comment: It would improve the readability of your code because the logic of the code wouldn't be diluted in those two repetitive `if`/`else`. It *might* improve the runtime slightly because using a library data structure is usually faster than reimplementing it yourself, because the library data structures and functions are optimised in ways you can't hope to optimise your own code.

Comment: Note that the slowest part of your code right now is due to the use of `input`. User input is slow.

Comment: I see, I'll try updating my code (I'm not quite familiar with `collections.defaultdict` so I might research about it for awhile). Do you have a sample version of my code modified with your idea?

Comment: Important note: `list(x)` does not create a singleton list containing the element `x`. It creates a list from the iterator `x`. This means that `list(3)` would fail with error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`; and `list('AB')` would return `['A', 'B']` In the very particular case of a string of one character, we get `list('A') == ['A']`, but it's kind of a coincidence.

Comment: Thus it would be preferable to write `[temp[0]]` rather than `list(temp[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following improvements:

- Write `[temp[0]]` rather than `list(temp[0])` to create a one-element list, because `list` does not behave the way you think it does;
- Use `set` instead of `list` to deal with the duplicate issue;
- Use `collections.defaultdict` instead of `dict` to trim the `if`/`else` forest;
- Encapsulate your code in a function that reads from a file parameter rather than calling `input()`; the function can be called with parameter `sys.stdin` to get user input, or with `open('filename.txt', 'r')` to read from a file.
- Cleanly separate the "read from input" from the "write to output" in your code.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from sys import stdin

def read_graph(fileobject):
  graph = defaultdict(list)
  vertices = sorted(next(fileobject).split())
  m = int(next(fileobject))
  for line in fileobject:
    a, b = line.split()
    graph[a].append(b)
    graph[b].append(a)
  return graph

def print_graph_sorted(graph):
  for u, neighbours in sorted(graph.items()):
    print('{}: '.format(u), end='')
    for v in sorted(neighbours):
      print(v, end=' ')
    print()

def main():
  graph = read_graph(stdin)
  print_graph_sorted(graph)

if __name__=='__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: This is an exercise in our class so we cannot change input. I apologize for not mentioning.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "we cannot change input". The code I suggest reads from input exactly like yours.

Comment: You mentioned about taking input from a file.

Comment: Function `read_graph` reads its input from a *file object*. It's a standard python class to deal with input and output. However, when `main` calls `read_graph`, it gives it the parameter `sys.stdin`, standard input. So the program as a whole reads from standard input just like yours did.

Comment: I see, I guess I misunderstood what you said. Anyway, I tried running your code but it is not doing anything based from the sample input. Am I supposed to merge your code with my current?

Comment: It works fine on my machine. How did you try to run it?

Comment: I modified a part of your code specifically after taking m. It's kind of working right now.

Comment: I realized that we missed something, we should ignore if input is a vertex to itself like `A A` and I don't think your code considers that.

Comment: Feel free to add `if a != b:` at the appropriate place!

Answer (score 2):

i did not investigate the complexity of this, but with the [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) library you would get the desired results with this:

```
import networkx as nx

strg = """A B
C B
E C
D C
G D
F D
D E
E F"""


G = nx.parse_adjlist(strg.split("\n"))

for item in G.adjacency():
    print(f"{item[0]}:   {', '.join(sorted(item[1].keys()))}")
```

it outputs:

```
A:   B
B:   A, C
C:   B, D, E
E:   C, D, F
D:   C, E, F, G
G:   D
F:   D, E
```